# error: lvalue required in while ((*arg_to)++ = (*arg_from)++);

Tags: c++, pointers, lvalue

`arg_to` and `arg_from` are of type `char*`

1. `while (*(arg_to++) = *(arg_from++));`
2. `while ((*arg_to)++ = (*arg_from)++);`

Why does the first expression work properly whereas the second one throws the following error:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: Because `((*arg_to)++)` is not an lvalue. It's like you're saying `x + 2 = 3`.

Comment: May I convince you, "Don't border. Just never write this kind of thing."?

Comment: @RaymondChen Why is that not considered lvalue? Please explain in an answer.

Comment: The postfix operator returns the old value. If it were returning the object itself, you'd get the incremented version.